# How to find all the messages in a python protobuff

Tags: python, protocol-buffers

I have a python google-protobuff, now I wanna find all the messages in this protobuff file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a bit crude, but:

```
>>> import protobufmodule
>>> from google.protobuf.message import Message
>>> messageClasses = [v for v in  vars(protobufmodule).values() if isinstance(v, type) and issubclass(v, Message)]
```